# Why is some folder and file created in 'user' folder using Anaconda?

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda

Below image is snapshot in "C:\Users\myname"

[image]

What is it?? and how can I change directory for that?(I want move it into one folder)

I want to maintain C:\Users\myname folder clean

Comment: You cannot. These are configuration files for those programs, and they rely on being in that folder.

Comment: @darthbith Is there any way to change that files when reinstalling Anaconda?

Comment: Sure, you can delete them at any time, they're just configuration it shouldn't hurt anything.

Comment: @darthbith Aha, Thank you!!